# Using External Users in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I received a message from Apple indicating that **External Testers feature** is now available in **Itunes Connect**. I followed the next steps:

- Added a new External Tester.
- I switched on the Beta Testing option, and sent to Beta App Review.
- Filled the form and sent.

When I open the Testflight app there are no builds for testing and the person who I added as External Tester didn't receive any e-mail.

Did I forget any step? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the external beta testing, you need to pass the Beta app review. The app will be available to testflight and External testers will get mails only after your app is approved for beta testing.

> Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and
>   must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing
>   can begin. A review is required for new versions of your app that
>   contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time,
>   internally or externally.

Reference : [Beta testing](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/)

Image from iTunes Connect, when you create a beta testing.

[image: External testing]

Comment: So I need to pass a Beta App Review before sending it to the external testers and then, when everything is ok I need to pass another Review, that's it? So I need to pass a Beta App Review before sending it to the external testers and then, when everything is ok I need to pass another Review, that's it? I think that it is a strange process, since I only have to upload an AdHoc Build to the Testflight platform and my testers will be able to download it. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielRivera: Unfortunately, that is the process. I'm directly using testflight because of this strange process !!!

Comment: unfortunately testflight will be terminated

Comment: I just saw this too, which means we no longer allow to push small features to testers anymore ?

Comment: @cherhan: You can use iTunes connect internal testing or any third-party sites (similar like test-flight)

Comment: Any suggestion for third-party?

Comment: @cherhan: There are a lot of tools, some of them are [diawi](http://www.diawi.com), [Ubertesters](http://ubertesters.com)